# Tanto Windows como Ubuntu no reconoce el movil pero si otros dispositivos

Tags: android-studio, windows, ubuntu, usb

La pregunta es bastante común, pero he intentado mil soluciones que he encontrado en Internet y ninguna me ha solucionado nada.
El problema es que mi portátil no reconoce ningun movil, pero por ejemplo un disco duro externo no tiene problemas, puedo copiar, borrar archivos lo que sea.
Tengo dos puertos, uno 2.0 que ni sale la conexión y en ubuntu da error y otro 3.0 que en windows lo reconoce pero sale vacio literalmente, ninguna carpeta siquiera, y en ubuntu se conecta y desconecta o ni llega a conectarse.
He probado varios moviles y varios cables y ninguno funciona cuando han ido sin problemas en otros ordenadores.
Espero ayuda, estoy trabajando con android studio y es imposible debuguear sin tener el movil conectado.

Comment: Sería importante agregar características de tu móvil para tener mas idea del problema. Recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], ¿tu móvil tiene habilitado el modo dev ? saludos.

Comment: He activado y desactivado el modo desarrollador y ma depuración, borrado y reinstalado los drivers, instalado kies, todl lo que he encontrado por internet. Y lo máximo que he llegado a conseguir es que lo reconozca pero salga vacia, lo raro que es en los dos sistemas operativos.